# Why isn't there a "main" ERC-20 smart contract to reference?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

In object-oriented programming, you can often extend or rename functions.

This functionality would be helpful in smart contracts, because you'd only have to pay for the gas for any incremental lines of code. (As opposed to now, where it seems like you have to re-upload all ERC-20 code to Ethereum for each new contract.)

Why doesn't it work like this in Solidity?

Comment: each ERC20 code is a different  token, so it is ok to upload it again, because it is different object. Same goes for Java or C++. If you have a class, you create multiple objects of this same class by calling `new`

Answer (score 2):

Solidity has the concept of [libraries](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#libraries), which were meant just for that kind of code reuse. You can deploy a library once and invoke its external functions from multiple versions of your contract.

For various reasons this pattern did not gain much popularity, the most important one being probably the cost - `DELEGATECALL` used in external library calls is just as expensive as any other external call. It's cheaper to just use internal calls that result in the called function being included in your bytecode.